# asp.net Script registration - Sys is undefined even while using if condition

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

In my application more pages have got Script Manager in them hence my script which depends on them loads but in some static pages the script manager is not present since none of features of Asp.net ajax is used.
but even though i register my client script like below i get `Sys is undefined` error, why is 
that so.

```
if(Sys){
   Sys.Application.add_init(registerMyLibrary);
}
```

i had also tried below, but what the use when the above code itself throws error

```
if(Sys !== 'undefined'){
  //register my library
}
```

Is there some other way i can register my library without the error on my way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because it (`Sys`) hasn't been assigned in the global object or any shadowing context, which may be (read: likely is) another bigger issue.

In any case, `if (window.Sys) { ... }` will work as expected.

The problem is *the lookup resolution* for `Sys` fails and JavaScript raises the nice error (this is why the latter form with the `!==` also fails). This is not a problem when trying to access a *property* of the `window` object explicitly, as shown above. `window` is conveniently the global object in JavaScript in a browser.

The `window.Sys !== undefined` variant can be used as well, but I dislike it. Another alternative is `typeof Sys != "undefined"`, but I dislike this even more. (This works because `typeof` is a special operator and will not raise an exception if the lookup fails opting to return "undefined" -- the string -- instead.)

Happy coding.

Comment: awesome, i hadn't thought of the window global object good point there. Just a simple question how do i give a shortcut to my library like '$' that jquery does. i would like symbol '§' which is rarely used.thanks

Comment: @Deeptechtons `§` is not a valid JavaScript Identifier and `window['§']` isn't much of a shortcut :-) Slightly trivialized: `window.$$ = MyObjectOrNamespace // all there is to jQuery` (I would actually recommend looking at the jQuery source, it is a fairly good example of how to write a self-contained "module".)

Comment: '§' darn it, so your above code will be used like `$$('').getName()` if getName was method in my library? is there some example[reliable] on google that teaches me to wrap objects with method of the class. so that i can chain methods

Comment: @Deeptechtons `$$` had better evaluate to a function-object in that example! `jQuery` (aka `$`) is a function in the jQuery library, but it might not be the case in your library, depending on how it is to be used. It might be just `$$.getName()` or whatever is appropriate.